# What is $f^{−1}(B)$ for $B = \{{[0]_{10}}\}$, given $f(x) = [4x]_{10}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Consider the function $f : Z → Z/10Z$ defined by $f(x) = [4x]_{10}$. What is $f^{−1}(B)$ for

$B = \{{[0]_{10}}\}$?

I understand that in order to find this I need for find the set of all $x \in Z$ such that $[4x]_{10} \equiv [0]_{10}$, however I am unsure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** By definition, an element $x \in \Bbb Z$ satisfies $[4x]_{10} \equiv 0$ if and only if $4x$ is a multiple of $10$.

Comment: So would it be $(5/2)k$ for all $k \in Z$?

Comment: $x = 5/2$, for example, is not in the domain of the function.

Comment: Then just $x=5k$, $k \in Z$?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

when $x=0$, $f_{(x)}=[0]$,

when $x=1$, $f_{(x)}=[4]$,

when $x=2$, $f_{(x)}=[8]$,

when $x=3$, $f_{(x)}=[2]$,

when $x=4$, $f_{(x)}=[6]$,

when $x=5$, $f_{(x)}=[0]$, after this point, pattern repeats.

when $[x]_5\equiv[0] $,$f_{(x)}=[0]$

there for $f^{-1}([0]_{10})=[0]_5$